# Compare two CSV to Upsert (Insert or Update) by ID in Azure Synapse Analitycs or Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, csv, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse-analytics

I need to compare two CSV, when IDcsv1 is equal to IDcsv2, I need to update data. When IDcsv2 doesnt´t exist in csv1 I need to insert data.
If is posible, I want to update the most recent row, like the last modified.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AFAIK**, Currenlty upsert option is only supported for database datasets in ADF. As your requirement is about the csv files, this can be done in two ways.

**Using dataflows:**

**Target dataset** - data will be inserted or updated in this dataset.

[image]

Input dataset - data from this will be copied to target table.

[image]

So, I have taken these datasets, Sample2.csv as source and Sample1.csv as sink in the dataflow.

I have used **3 exists** transformation to get the rows.

1. for the rows which exists in target but not in source.
2. for the rows which exists in both target and source
3. for the rows which not exists in target but only in source.

Then I have used **union by Position** 2 times on these 3 results to get result data. Now, I have given this to sink and used the target dataset in sink.

This is my dataflow:

[image]

**My dataflow JSON for your reference:**

```
{
    "name": "dataflow1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "csv1sink",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "mysink"
                },
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "csv2source",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "mysource"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "csv1sink",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "joinrows"
                },
                {
                    "name": "sinkrows"
                },
                {
                    "name": "sourcerows"
                },
                {
                    "name": "union1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "union2"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(output(",
                "          csv1Id as string,",
                "          name as string",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> mysink",
                "source(output(",
                "          csv2Id as string,",
                "          name as string",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> mysource",
                "mysource, mysink exists(csv2Id == csv1Id,",
                "     negate:false,",
                "     broadcast: 'auto')~> joinrows",
                "mysink, mysource exists(csv1Id == csv2Id,",
                "     negate:true,",
                "     broadcast: 'auto')~> sinkrows",
                "mysource, mysink exists(csv2Id == csv1Id,",
                "     negate:true,",
                "     broadcast: 'auto')~> sourcerows",
                "sinkrows, joinrows union(byName: false)~> union1",
                "union1, sourcerows union(byName: false)~> union2",
                "union2 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     input(",
                "          csv1Id as string,",
                "          name as string",
                "     ),",
                "     partitionFileNames:['Sample1.csv'],",
                "     umask: 0022,",
                "     preCommands: [],",
                "     postCommands: [],",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     partitionBy('hash', 1)) ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Result after dataflow execution:

[image]

> If is posible, I want to update the most recent row, like the last modified.

To get this, the dataflow operations might get complicated as we first need to sort the target data(matched rows) based on the date and then update only the first matched date. If you want to do the above its better to follow the below approach.

**Using Stored procedure and temporary table from SQL:**
For this you need SQL database and a linked service for it with ADF. In this method, first use two lookup activities on both csv datasets. Pass the result JSON arrays to a stored procedure activity.

Created a stored procedure in SQL and write your logic to upsert in this. You can also write the logic for the case of updating based on last modified date. Store the result to a temporary table and create an ADF dataset for it.

[image]

After Stored procedure activity, use a copy activity with source as temporary table and sink to the target csv. This will copy the records from temporary table to the target csv file.

Comment: Thank you so much. For stored procedure I can´t use SQL database. Anyway I appreciate your information.